# Looking for data about collateral and safe asset

Tags: data-request, financial-markets

I'm supposed to report the evolution of the use of collateral on financial markets. I found some substantial data concerning the amount of collateral available (i.e. the amount of safe assets in the economy), but I can't get hold of numbers about the effective amount of collateral used and exchanged on the markets. Ideally, I'm looking for quarterly statistics.

I read a lot of research articles, but this is most of the time pages and pages of text and formulas, with no concrete numbers.

Any of you has an idea of where I could search what I need?

Comment: Don't know if this would help, but Quandl has a free database called ]US Federal Reserve Data Releases](https://www.quandl.com/data/FED) and it has quarterly datasets such as "10,000+; Secured by collateral; Domestic banks, Quarterly,"  "Prime; Secured by collateral; All commercial banks, Quarterly" etc. Would this be what you're looking for?